# Mac App Backwards Compatible to Yosemite

Tags: xcode, swift, macos, backwards-compatibility

I'm on El Capitan in XCode 7.3.1 and Swift 2 trying to make my mac application work on Yosemite (it just doesn't open at all with no crash logs).

- I have 10.10 set as the deployment target, but that didn't change anything.
- I downloaded Xcode 6.4 on another machine and loaded the project and it's complaining a ton about all of my swift code not being a thing.

I'm assuming (hoping) I don't have to figure out how to write this in an old version of Swift in order to make it work on Yosemite.

How do I know which features of the new SDK need to be made backwards compatible?

Comment: Try to check the system.log using the Console app, you might be able to find the crash backtrace there.

Comment: @A-Live, your comment led me to discover the problem, so if you want to post an answer (that sort of answers the spirit of my question), I'll accept it. :+1:

Comment: Glad to know it helped, please add your own answer, that will be more helpful for those who will find this question in the future.